# How to put all the TextInput value from a BrowserGallery into a Collection in PowerApps?

Tags: powerapps

I have a BrowserGallery that looks like this:
[image]

I can't figure out how to create a collection with all the values from all the TextInput and all the relatives Titles from the button click (the bold writings in the screenshots) I need a collection like this:
[image]

and so on..

What I have now is this:

```
ClearCollect(ThisBudget; {item: BrowseGallery1.AllItems.item; budget: BrowseGallery1.AllItems.TextInput1})
```

but is not giving me the result I want..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one:

```
ClearCollect(mycollection,ForAll(Gallery1.AllItems,{item:Heading,budget:Body}))
```

Replace Heading and Body with your Gallery controls.

Comment: How about patching this collection in order to change the budget value to te corresponding item?

Comment: The [function ForAll](https://powerapps.microsoft.com/en-us/tutorials/function-forall/) can be used to patch the items as well - take a look at [the documentation](https://powerapps.microsoft.com/en-us/tutorials/function-forall/) for more details.